# How to Create a Dropdown menu in Thesis Sidebar?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have an issue with Thesis Wordpress theme. I want to create a dropdown menu for my categories and archives in the sidebar, not the navigation menu.

If anyone knows how or can point me to a website where this is explained I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I dont't have the thesis theme but showing a dropdown for categories or archives is a standard WordPress Plugin. Just select them from the widgets page within your backend.

Comment: Wow, not that I'm not grateful, but this was asked 45 days ago, and I found the solution 44 days and 22 hours ago :)